# In Angular, is there a way to prevent flicker in expressions that contain concatenated values?

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to prevent flicker for templates that contain concatenated values such as `{{person.LastName+ ", " + person.FirstName}}`?

I don't want to see the "," until `$scope.person` is bound.

Is this something that I might put into a filter? Would you create a filter for something this trivial?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use `ng-show` for this.
I've created a demo to show the results.
http://plnkr.co/edit/ZAC8RzagPYmLHgXcPazW?p=preview

I'm using a timeout of 2 seconds in the controller so you can see the flicker if you remove ng-show.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the [ngCloak](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngCloak#!) directive for that. From the docs:

> The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the Angular html template
>   from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled)
>   form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid
>   the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.

Comment: ngCloak works if there is only one value such as person.LastName, but if the expression contains a ", " in it, the comma is rendered by itself for a brief second before the person object is bound.

Answer (score 5):

You can use "ng-bind" attribute in your wrapper tag so instead of this:

```
<span>{{person.LastName+ ", " + person.FirstName}}</span>
```

You can do this:

```
<span ng-bind="person.LastName + ', ' + person.FirstName"></span>
```

This will change the tag text only when the value is properly concatenated.

Answer (score 0):

Had some issues with ng-cloak so i resorted to using plain old css:

```
<div class="digits" style="display:none;">
```

And on the controller:

```
document.querySelector('.digits').style.display = 'block';
```

Answer (score -1):

This happens because you're loading your angular js lib not from the `<head></head>` section. If it's not a big deal to you, just move your angular `<script>` tag in the head and it should stop flickering.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I suspect because Angular needs a bit of time between when the browser loads the script and when it actually updates the expressions in the UI.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's really fast or not. In fact, the flicker appeared the exact same as if I loaded my script at the end of the HTML or in the `<head>`.