# Value of expression does not render on browser

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

The expression `{{heading + message}}` in my html should render, as per my code, as `Message:` .

It does render the values of the variables `heading` and `message` when I input the values and click the button.

So the intended functionality is working.

> But the question is about the initial load where the expression should
>   render as `Message:`  in place of the `expression` itself as in
>   `{{heading + message}}`.

I am accessing the page via `http://localhost:8080/examples/first.html`, and I have tried on safari and chrome.

**Nature of the problem:**

The expression renders as is: `{{heading + message}}` **for few seconds** on the first load (unless I refresh the page).

It  is eventually rendered but my question is why would it take a bit to render the title `Message:` in my .js file.

I am not certain, it couldn't be the processor because I am running it on ***Node.js / Express server on osx with 2.4 GHz Intel Core i5***

**The HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="firstApp">
<head>
    <title>First AngularJS App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="FirstController">
        <span>Name:</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="first" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="last" />
        <button ng-click="updateMessage()">Message</button>
        <hr>
        {{heading + message}}
    </div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/first.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**The .js:**

```
var firstApp = angular.module('firstApp', []);
firstApp.controller('FirstController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.first = '';
    $scope.last = '';
    $scope.heading = 'Message: ';
    $scope.updateMessage = function () {
        $scope.message = 'Hello ' + $scope.first + ' ' + $scope.last + ' !';
    };
});
```

*Any pointers would be helpful. Following are the screen shots of what it looks like initially for a moment vs. after a few seconds:*

[image: Expression]

**vs.**

[image: value]

**EDIT: It isn't so just on the the first load. This happens on subsequent loads on new tabs as well, not as slow as the first load but it does happen.**
Anything you think I should try different?

Comment: `ngCloak` will prevent you from seeing the unparsed Angular before the script is loaded.

Comment: @tymeJV do you mean `ngCloak` is working by default?

Comment: It's not working by default if you see the unparsed expression on initial load. My guess is, initial load has to go and download the Angular script from the CDN, then run it. Subsequent loads used the cached version and are much faster.

Comment: that doesn't really help me. I did fiddle but all in vain. Could you please explain a bit more. Do you mean the slow rendering is unavoidable? I hope not.

Comment: YES @tymeJV I believe you are correct as this is what I answered as well and has been what I have encountered many times with both angular and jquery (any other large js lib for that matter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think as per the ngCloak doc ,which will get rid of the flickering issue https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

, ng-cloak works is it adds display: none !important to items using it.

```
   [ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak,    .x-ng-cloak {
    display: none !important;
  }
```

This directive can be applied to the body element, but the preferred usage is to apply multiple ngCloak

```
   <span ng-cloak>{{heading + message}}</span>
```

**as per the doc of ng-cloak , make sure angular.js script must be loaded in the head section of the html file for the better results**,

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using AngularJS directive ngCloak, use class="ng-cloak", Angular will automatically remove it once it has loaded all of the module's dependencies.

You will have to add this line to your CSS file:

```
.ng-cloak {
  display:none;
}
```

Add the class to your body tag:

```
<body class="ng-cloak">
```

Here's a working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/v3DnDb2dJIqMAvxkEsO2?p=preview

Comment: I do not want to add yet another file for this.

Comment: no I do not. I am keeping as simple as possible...no need of any css, just apps and modules...playing with dependency injections.

Comment: In that case shushanth's answer might suit you better, but know that placing scripts on the head section makes rendering slower, which in your case I guess that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely attributed to the fact that your scripts are being called from a remote server instead of from your testing server's local file system (I am thinking this due to the face that you stated it hangs while only rendering 2 variables which would not cause any real delay in rendering - to the naked eye), so while the get happens your browser does not know what to do with the Angular code until the library is downloaded, parsed and executed.

I would download a copy of AngularJS along with any other dependencies that nG may be using into your projects public scripts directory and then retest. I am willing to be that this solves your latency issues. The only other obvious thing it could be is the amount of data-binding expressions this view has - although if this the code above is the only angular you have on this page, then you can rule the amount of bindings out as a problem. I think one doesn't experience real  latency issues until about roughly 10,000 data bindings (basically AngularJS is known for a ton of things - rendering speed is not one of them).

Also you can avoid the "expression flicker" by using `ng-bind` in place of the `{{ ngExpressions }}`.

You may also use `<div ng-show="heading && message"> {{ heading }} {{ message }}</div>`

or `ngCloak`. These techniques are are covered in this thread: [In Angular, is there a way to prevent flicker in expressions that contain concatenated values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599144/in-angular-is-there-a-way-to-prevent-flicker-in-expressions-that-contain-concat)