# How to show load and show label from scope variable in angularjs without page flicker

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to load a label into html form.  The page loads fine but with a flicker.

My html:

index.html:

```
<div id="main" role="main">
<div ng-include="'search/search.tpl.html'"></div>
</div>
```

search/search.tpl.html

```
<div class="someClass" ng-controller="SearchCtrl">
<div class="col4 col5">
    <h2 class="f-abcd">{{sectionhead}}</h2>  // i am not using label for="clazz",  but h2 tag. 
</div>
</div>
```

js:

```
angular.module('app').controller('SearchCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.sectionhead = 'FooBar...';
}]);
```

Angular does it, but page loads there is a flicker.  How to prevent this flicker.  I googled out, and they point to ng-show, ng-hide, promises, but not sure, if they really mean for a label (constant data).  Can someone point to right direction, I will be grateful.

I also wonder if this can be actually extended to load all label texts,for all html tags (h1, h2 etc and label/values from a file and change then per locale.

Comment: What do you mean by flickr? If it displays template in uncompiled form then you can use [ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)

Comment: Sorry meant a undesirable flicker effect, which I believe could be from the html template compilation.  I tried ng-cloak: per  [link]https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak and per link (they have mentioned ng-cloak/ng-bind:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599144/in-angular-is-there-a-way-to-prevent-flicker-in-expressions-that-contain-concat.  Tried both, doesn't work.    <h2 class="f-abcd" ng-cloak>{{sectionhead}}</h2>    and  <h2 class="f-abcd" ng-bind="sectionhead"></h2>

Comment: it went away after adding rest of the html elements in the page below this section.  Wierd though.  Might be a oversight.  Thanks Ubaid though :)